# Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename' + Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Im making an MVC WEB API project.

I have the follow connectionstring on development environment:

```
<add name="ContextoIsolucionV4" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=WOLVERINE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Isolucion40DesarrolloMC;password=isolucion; User=isolucion; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

And when I make the publish and test the site (making a AJAX request) to an ApiController returns me the follow exception:

ExceptionMessage: "Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'."

```
ExceptionType: "System.ArgumentException"
Message: "An error has occurred."
StackTrace: "   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString.VerifyLocalHostAndFixup(String& host, Boolean enforceLocalHost, Boolean fixup)
↵   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connect
```

The full stacktrace is:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString.VerifyLocalHostAndFixup(String& host, Boolean enforceLocalHost, Boolean fixup)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__18(DbConnection t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()\r\n   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)\r\n   at Isolucion.Aplicacion.Implementaciones.ServicioAplicacionUsuario.Autenticar(String nombreUsuario, String contraseña)\r\n   at Isolucion.Servicios.WebApi.Controllers.UsuarioController.Login(LoginDto loginDto)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Any suggestion ?? This is because Im using entity framework 6 ??

Help !!

Comment: it doesn't look like your context is using that SQL Connection string.  are there any others in your web.config?

Comment: this is not an Entity Connection string please set your connection string as EF documentation. please have a look on it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716756(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Solved ... The trouble was that the name of the connection string do not matches with the name that was in the ctor of the context ... On any way thanks for your help ...